# Java, create a file and a folder

Tags: java, io

I am creating files with Java in Windows. This works:

```
String newFile = "c:/"+Utilities.timeFormat();
...
some code that creates a folder
```

This does not work:

```
String newFile = "c:/newDirectory/"+Utilities.timeFormat();
...
some code that creates a folder
```

Comment: Does newDirectory exist prior to you trying to write to the new file?

Comment: [Java documentation. File mkdir()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) [Java documentation. File mkdirs()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) Last include creation of nonexistant directories.

Comment: The first time it is run (on many machines) the directory does not exist. After the first time, then directory will have been created.

Comment: `"c:/"+Utilities.timeFormat();` 1-a) Put files in a sub-directory of `user.home` 1-b) User home is a reliable path on Mac. & *nix, as well as Windows.  2) Don't use `String` objects to represent a `File`. 3) Form paths using valid separators with the `new File(parentFile, "thefilename")` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `File.mkdir()` or `File.mkdirs()` method to [create a folder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

EDIT:

```
 String path="c:/newDirectory";
 File file=new File(path);
 if(!file.exists())
     file.mkdirs(); // or file.mkdir()

 file=new File(path + "/" + Utilities.timeFormat());   
 if(file.createNewFile())
  {
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. What it seems that I might need to do is: 1) IF(folder does not exist) {create the folder;} 2) Place new file in folder.

Answer (score 1):

without knowing your actual code which is creating the directory:

use mkdirs() instead of mkdir()

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you have permissions to create a folder in `c:/`?

Can you show us the stacktrace too?

Answer (score 0):

If "newDirectory" doesn't exist yet, you should use the method `mkdirs()` from the `File` class to create all the directories in between.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the directory doesn't exist is probably why it isn't working he first time through.  As many have pointed out use mkdirs() will ensure if the file you want to write is in subfolders it will create them.  Now here is what it might look like:

```
File file = new File( new File("c:/newDirectory"), Utilities.timeFormat() );
if( !file.getParentFile().exists() ) {
   file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
OutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( file ) );
try {
   // put your code here to write the file
} finally {
   stream.close();
}
```

Notice I'm not using + to create a path. Instead I create a File object, and pass it the parent File and the name of the file.  Also notice I'm not putting path separators in between the parent and filename.  Using the File constructor takes care of a system independent way of creating paths.